# J-Meter gives false results

Tags: automation, jmeter, performance-testing

I'm trying to learn J-Meter.

When I'm running a sample script of logging into a site using both valid/invalid credentials,it doesn't stop thread execution when invalid login credential is used and also login is not recorded in database.

Does it actually login to the website or only creates virtual login to create a similar environment.Is there any way to achieve this  using Samplers?

Answer (score 1):

JMeter is/acts as a `headless browser`.

Whatever your browser with an UI does, JMeter can also do - except executing a javascript. So, If you had recorded your script correctly - JMeter can login to the actual application as well.

Jmeter is not like QTP/Selenium. It does not know if it is a valid credential/invalid credential. It passes/fails the request based on the HTTP codes. If the HTML response from the server comes with a 200 http code, It passed for JMeter. If the server responds with code 500, JMeter fails the request. But JMeter also provides a way to validate the response you get - `Assertion`. You can use `Response Assertion` to see if you are seeing the home page or not to confirm if the user has logged in successfully.

To stop the test on error, select the appropriate option here in `thread Group` properties.

[image]

JMeter is a very nice tool & have been using it for 2 years with no issues.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Vinoth, I used Response Assertion to find <title>Dashboard</title> ,which is visible to only logged in users.But it is showing error instead.Even when used valid credentials.

Comment: Add the response assertion as a child element of HTTP sampler which sends the login request. it is very sensitive search. So just look for `Dashboard`

Answer (score 1):

Does your script have `Config Element -> HTTP Cookie Manager`? It needs cookie for the login function.

If your script has many transactions with the same level with login transaction and the option you select in your Thread Group is `Continue`, all transactions will be executed no matter login transaction is passed or failed.

In case you want the other transactions will not be executed if login fails, let add a `Regular Expression Extractor` as child of the login transaction to retrieve the text `Dashboard`, put other transactions into a `Logic Controller -> If Controller`. Suppose the `Regular Expression Extractor` has name `Dashboard` and `Default value` is `NotFound`, then the Condition of `If Controller` will be `"${Dashboard}"!="NotFound"`

Answer (score 1):

JMeter automatically treats 2xx and 3xx HTTP Response Codes successful so it won't be able to detect failed login unless you explicitly tell it to check presence or absence of some specific content in the response data.

So if you add a [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) you will be able to conditionally fail sampler and choose what to do in case of failure via "Action to be taken after a  Sampler error" on [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level.

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) guide for more details on the assertions domain.

If you're unsure what JMeter Sampler is doing you can check request and response details via [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener. If you cannot simulate login event in majority of cases it is due to missing [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) and/or failed correlation of dynamic mandatory parameter(s) like Viewstate, CSRF token, etc.